# Decrement date by 1 on button press

Tags: iphone, nsdateformatter

I am using a date formatter string in order to get the current date as follows:

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"EEEE / dd-MM-yyyy";
timeLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Now i need to decrement the date by 1 on a button press, If the the date today is Friday/05-08-2011, then on button press it should display Thursday/04-08-2011.
How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code like this (in addition to above answer)

`- dateByAddingTimeInterval:` available in 4.0 and later, you can use `- addTimeInterval` for lower version (deprecated in 4.0 or later).

```
-(IBAction)decrementDate
{
    NSString *dateForDecrement=timeLabel.text;
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"EEEE / dd-MM-yyyy";
    NSDate *dateObjectForDecrement=[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateForDecrement];

    NSDate *dateAfterDecrement=[dateObjectForDecrement addTimeInterval:-(24*60*60)];
     timeLabel.text =  [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateAfterDecrement];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The trick is to use time intervals. The [Date and Time Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtDates.html) has some more information on this.

Basically, `NSDate` has a method that allows you to add a time interval to the current date.

```
- (id)dateByAddingTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds
```

In order to get yesterday's date, you want to grab today's date and subtract 24*60*60 (total # of seconds in one day) from it.

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDate *yesterday = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval: -86400.0];
```

Does that help?

Comment: @Sadumerry: Provide ur date instead of today's date in the answer. Update that date after subtracting the timeInterval